# Why is my image upload not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to upload the images dropped on to the dropzone element in the bottom of the following page:

>

In my insert button, I get the `src` and `filenames` of each image as follows:

```
var img_arr = [];
var img_arr_filenames = [];
var i=0;
$("#my-dropzone img").each(function(){
   img_arr.push(this.src);
   img_arr.push("%imgend%");

   img_arr_filenames.push(this.alt);
   img_arr_filenames.push("%filenameend%");

});
var imgs = img_arr;
var img_names = img_arr_filenames;
```

and then send the info to php function via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://betastream.com.au/skybidv3/auth/insert_auction/',
    type: 'POST',  
    data: (imgs:imgs, img_names:img_names}), 
    success: function(html) {
      alert("Auction Added");
    }
})
```

And try to write the images on php function but no images are written on the server, what have I done wrong ?

```
function insert_auction()
{ 
    $img_names_array = explode("%filenameend%", $_POST['img_names']);
    $imgs_array = explode("%imgend%", $_POST['imgs']);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($imgs_array as $temp)
    {

        $img = $temp;
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = 'testimage.png';//$img_names_array[$i];
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
        $i = $i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like looking at what `$img_names_array` and `$imgs_array` looks like? You're simply assuming your JS code is perfect.

Comment: `this.src` does not contain the image's binary data. It contains the filename on the server. So, what you are doing is sending file paths to PHP and treating it as binary data.

Comment: Here is the alert display after adding alert("img_names:"+ img_names+"img_arr: " + img_arr); http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ylmru1.jpg  Is this is not the data i'm supposed to use to write ?

Comment: where have you written the move_uploaded_file have you written it in your ajax call to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to post just files ulrs to the server, but not images themselves. To upload images as binary data you may use form multipart and post the form with js. There are a lot of existing file uploaders, for example [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) you may use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can't upload files using normal ajax. You should use a plugging for that .You can use ajaxFileUploader plugging. That worked fine for me.

```
Here is the link
```

[ajax File uploader](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)